# How to check if all images are completely uploaded into my MVC application folder and then send these images in email body?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, image-uploading, file-search

I am uploading multiple images to my folder asynchronously using XMLHttpRequest. After the all images are completely loaded to folder I need to send an email which contains these images in the email body part as well as attachment. My question is how do I check if all the images are completely uploaded to my folder. I have tried the following:

```js
 $scope.UploadFile = function (inputFile) {
        var j = inputFile.length;
        var filenames = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inputFile.length; i++) {
            $scope.UploadFileIndividual(inputFile[i].file,
                                        inputFile[i].file.name,
                                        inputFile[i].file.type,
                                        inputFile[i].file.size,
                                        i, inputFile.length);
            filenames[i] = inputFile[i].file.name;
            j--;
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/RFQ/SendEmail/',
                data: { RFQValues: $scope.RFQData, fileNames: filenames}
            }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                if (response == true) {
                    window.location.href = '/CheckOut/ThankYou';
                }
            }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                // alert('Your Selection Not Added to Cart');
            });
        }
    } ; 
    $scope.UploadFileIndividual = function (fileToUpload, name, type, size, index, fileArrayLength) {
        var reqObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
       
        //open the object and set method of call(get/post), url to call, isasynchronous(true/False)
        reqObj.open("POST", "/RFQ/UploadFiles", true);

        //set Content-Type at request header.For file upload it's value must be multipart/form-data
        reqObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        //Set Other header like file name,size and type
        reqObj.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', name);
        reqObj.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', type);
        reqObj.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', size);

        // send the file
        reqObj.send(fileToUpload);
    };
```

This is my controller method to upload images:

```
  public virtual string UploadFiles(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            var length = Request.ContentLength;
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, length);

            var fileName = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            var fileSize = Request.Headers["X-File-Size"];
            var fileType = Request.Headers["X-File-Type"];
            string path = @"~\images\Client Images";
            string subPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString() + "_" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();
            string finalPath = Server.MapPath(path + @"\" + subPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(finalPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(finalPath);
            var saveToFileLoc = finalPath + @"\" + fileName;

            // save the file.
            var fileStream = new FileStream(saveToFileLoc, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, length);
            fileStream.Close();

            var usrid = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString());
            using (DataContext _db = new DataContext())
            {
                int RFQId = _db.RFQDetailss.OrderByDescending(x => x.RFQId).Where(x => x.UserId == usrid && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.RFQ_CreatedDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)).Select(y => y.RFQId).FirstOrDefault();

                RFQClientImage objClientImage = new RFQClientImage();
                objClientImage.RFQId = RFQId;
                objClientImage.ImagePath = @"images\Client Images\" + subPath + @"\" + fileName;
                _db.RFQClientImages.Add(objClientImage);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return string.Format("{0} bytes uploaded", bytes.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        } 
    }
```

I have then checked on js side if all files are sent for uploading and then in controller also I am checking if currently uploaded files exists in the folder by following code:

```
public JsonResult SendEmail(RFQFormInfo RFQValues, string[] fileNames)
    {
        bool IsMailSent = false;
        try
        {
            string directoryPath = @"~\images\Client Images\";
            string subDirectoryPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString() + "_" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() + @"\";
            //string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(directoryPath + subDirectoryPath));
            string targetPath = Server.MapPath(directoryPath + subDirectoryPath);
            IsMailSent = checkifImageUploaded(RFQValues, getFilesList(targetPath), fileNames);
            return Json(IsMailSent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(IsMailSent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    public bool checkifImageUploaded(RFQFormInfo RFQValues, IEnumerable<string> fileEntries, string[] fileNames)
    {
        bool IsMailSent = false;
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string directoryPath = @"~\images\Client Images\";
            string subDirectoryPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString() + "_" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString() + @"\";
            string targetPath = Server.MapPath(directoryPath + subDirectoryPath);
            foreach (string filename in fileNames)
            {
                var currentFile = Server.MapPath(directoryPath + subDirectoryPath + filename);
                 foreach(var file in fileEntries)
                 {
                     if (file.Equals(currentFile))
                     {
                         counter++;
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 if (counter == fileNames.Length)
                     break;
            }
            if (counter == fileNames.Length)
            {
                IsMailSent = SendRFQMail(RFQValues, fileNames);
                return IsMailSent;
            }
            else
                checkifImageUploaded(RFQValues, getFilesList(targetPath), fileNames);

            return IsMailSent;
        }
        catch
        {
            return IsMailSent;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> getFilesList(string targetDirectory)
    {
        var fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory);
        return fileEntries;
    }
```

but my checkIfImageUploaded() function throws stack overflow exception. I understand it is because my code is ending up into infinite loop or recursion but what I don't understand is at what point is my code ending into infinite recursion and how to solve it.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You entering infinite loop because of recursion in your code. this part - `if (counter == fileNames.Length)` is never returning true.

Comment: I don't understand logic behind your check function. It's checking if all files are uploaded, if not running same function recursively, so whats the point of that? What will happen if some of files will not be uploaded? The infinite loop.

Comment: I am checking because I want to wait till all files get uploaded. It's happening such that If I upload say 6 files. First 4 files get uploaded and my SendMail() function is called and then the next 2 files are getting uploaded. I want to wait till all 6 files are uploaded or have attempted to upload and then only send the email and if there's any error while uploading then email should get sent with successfully uploaded files.

Comment: I understand checking logic, the thing is I dont understand, is the logic behind Your checking function, cause how I said earlier, if one of the files will not be uploaded it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok I understood. But then how do I identify that all files have attempted to upload. My concern is I don't want to send email before atleast all images have attempted to upload. I am not aware if there is any inbuilt function in .NET which notifies about file been written completely to the folder.